# Generating colors for data points in R

Tags: r, colors

I have some data points such as:

```
1.342 0.1839 1.1 2.210
```

and I want to generate a vector that has

```
0-1: red
1-2: green
2-3: blue
```

so for this vector, it would be

```
red green green blue
```

that way I can plot with colors and the points will be colored according to the values of my data points.

Here is a reproducible example of why it is wrong. Some dots are black:

```
library(rgl)
library(Rcmdr)
x <- c(1:10)
y <- c(2,4,5,1,8,4,6,2,3,1)
z <- c(3,6,1,7,8,3,5,5,7,9)
c <- c(0.1, 0.2, 1.2, 1.8, 2.4, 1.2, 0.6, 0.6, 1.3, 2.1)

cols <- cut(c, breaks=c(0, 1, 2, 3), labels=c("red", "green", "blue"))

scatter3d(x,y,z,residuals=F,fit=NA,point.col=cols)
```

Comment: try `cut(x, 0:3, labels = c('red', 'green', 'blue'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the general idea:

```
dat <- c(1.342, 0.1839, 1.1, 2.210)
plot(dat, 
     col = as.character(cut(dat, 
                            breaks=c(0, 1, 2, 3), 
                            labels=c("red", "green", "blue"))), 
     pch = 16)
```

(Note that the value of `cut()` is a factor, and so needs to be wrapped in `as.character()`. Otherwise, it will be interpreted by `col=` as a numeric vector with (always) 1="black", 2="red", 3="green", etc.)

Comment: hm that's not working with scatter3d. the colors are coming out black, green, and red instead of red, green, and blue. any idea why?

Comment: My bad, now fixed. `cols` was a factor, when it needs to be a character vector.

Comment: How can one add a legend indicating which range the colors refers to?

Comment: @g256 -- Add a legend to what kind of plot? In base graphics, see the examples `?legend`. If you still can't figure it out then, ask as a question (rather than here where no one but me will ever see it!).